# spring-boot secutiry - invoked method after authorizating user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to set some thing in context (more exactly it is database context holder) after successfull authentication user. I have properly configured spring-security. Credentials are passed by headers (but here It doesn't matter). Sequent requestsa are augmented by SESSION ID.

Everything is fine, I need only to implement some function which is automatically invoked **immediately** after acceptance of the request as authorized.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an authentication successfully completes, Spring Security will fire a [`AuthenticationSuccessEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AuthenticationSuccessEvent.html) event. You just need to register an event listener to listen to that event and provide a callback which will be executed after this event being fired:

```
@Component
class SuccessfulAuthenticationListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        // Put the function which is automatically invoked immediately 
        // after acceptance of the request as authorized.
    }
}
```

In order to intercept every authorized request, just register a plain filter and check that if user is authenticated or not:

```
@Component
class AuthorizedRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                    HttpServletResponse response, 
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            // do whatever is necessary
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What about something like `OnSuccessfullogin` ?

Comment: Ok, but is it ok for me ? I mean if it will be invoked after **each** acceptance of the request as authorized.

Comment: Yeap it will be

Comment: every request each has proper SESSION ID or credintials, simply each request that it returns NOT 401

Comment: thanks. To my eye it is not need to do this condition. This method is only invoked on authenticated request.

Comment: Since this filter will be registered after security filter chain, the `isAuthenticated` check would be useless if all your endpoints are protected by spring security. Otherwise you'll need this check to make sure that this filter will only be called for protected endpoints

Comment: ok, in my case all endpoints are secured that there is no need to `isAuthenticated`. Thanks!

Comment: maybe is there exists some way to invoke filter after `RequestContextHolder` is set ? At this moment this context during filter is not set. After invoking `doChainFilter` it is set.